# Unread books, unwatched videos, but what about podcasts, songs and other audio?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When we talk about books we haven't read yet, we call them unread books.

When we talk about movies and other videos we haven't watched yet, we call them unwatched ones.

But what about podcasts, songs and other audio? I have googled for "unlistened", but it seems this word is not really popular in this context, and instead it is more common to call such podcasts, songs, and other audio "unplayed". Is it really so?

Comment: Because we say "I've listened *to* it" a simple adjective from the verb's past participle, "listened", doesn't exist. **unheard** might work, even though we don't use **hear** as a perfect synonym for "listen to".

Comment: Lots of Google hits for "unheard songs". You could check specific software - surely Apple or Spotify has some way of labeling what you haven't listened to yet.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice This is really intesrting, thanks.

Comment: I think "unplayed" would work for both videos and audio recordings.  Unheard would mean something like nobody has ever heard it before, which is a bit weird in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unplayed", For example

> How do I get unplayed episodes to show up in Up Next section of Apple Podcasts?
> [source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254190480?sortBy=best)

That works for songs, videos, podcasts and anything else that you "play".